NextAuth session not showing UserId in Server-side component
I am working on small side project using next auth for login via Google provider.
I need to use userId in my serverside component.
I extended my auth handler with required callbacks according documentation and add console logs for jwt and session. Both sucescfully shows userid in console.
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  callbacks: {
    session: async ({ session, token }:any) => {
      if (session?.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
      }
      console.log("session",session)
      return session;
    },
    jwt: async ({ user, token }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.uid = user.id;
      }
      console.log("token",token)
      return token;
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

But when I use getServerSession it is not showing anything outside of email,name and image.
const OwnedCoursesPage = async () => {
  const session = (await getServerSession(handler)) as Session;
  console.log(session.user)
  // logs only name,email,image
  const userId = session?.user.id;
  const courses = await prisma.userCourse.findMany({
    where: {
      userId: userId,
    }
  });
return (
    <>
);
};


Any help please?
Extended module, various console logs but nothing helped.

Hey, one question: is the userId stored correctly in the Prisma database?
